# What is the difference between a fork node and a decision node?

Tags: uml

I have been reading my java book for class and I have a question about diagrams.

What is the difference between a fork node and a decision node?

Comment: Why is this tagged java and c#?

Comment: You need to indicate what *kind* of diagram it is as well. UML Object? Some actual Java class? Flowchart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about UML then... [this page covers that](https://web.archive.org/web/20160302153148/https://www.gentleware.com/fileadmin/media/archives/userguides/poseidon_users_guide/activitydiagram.html) (and other UML elements)

- A fork node is a control node that splits a flow into multiple concurrent flows. Think of it as starting multiple concurrent tasks.
- A decision node is a control node that chooses between outgoing flows. Think of it as an `if`-statement in Java or C#.